# CSS body background-image not showing in IE-6

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-6, background-image

I have some problem with the background-image property in IE-6. In all other browsers, background-image is showing except IE-6. This is the url of my site http://indivar.info/godsak/node/2.

This is what I have written in the css.

```
body {
background-color: #D3D3D3;
background: url("../images/background.jpg") repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
position:relative;
overflow-x:hidden;
}.
```

This question will lool outdated as this is related to IE-6. But the client needs it so I have to fix it. One more thing to clear I have checked on windows XP service pack 3 IE-6, there also its working fine. So problem with the IE-6 sp-2 of windows. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have background-color defined and then replaced with transparency in background. This may fix the problem?

Comment: I also have checked by removing the background-color. But this is also not working.

Comment: @samir chauhan - shows up ok in my IE6 (running in ietester) - you mean wooden texture, right? Try removing overflow-x out. Also have you tested on sp2 or did your client report that? Cause you won't believe what all people report as bugs and than you find out it's their pc messing.

Comment: @ easwee : My client report that to test on sp2.  Yes the wooden texture I need in the background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> yes in IE Tester it shows fine. But I am using adobe browserlab.
>   http://browserlab.adobe.com/en-us/

Then BrowserLab might be misleading you.

Testing with your live site, it works fine in IE6 here: http://ipinfo.info/netrenderer/

And it works fine in *genuine IE6* - I tested it myself locally using a virtual machine.

I don't think there's an actual problem here.

Comment: Yea I don't really trust Adobe when it comes to coding (*khm* flash player *khm*).

Answer (score 2):

Instead of doing shorthand try:

```
body {
background-image: url("../images/background.jpg");
background-repeat: repeat;
background-color: transparent;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
position:relative;
overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

This may/may not work

Comment: What IE6 are you using? My IETester & IE NetRenderer show it fine: http://ipinfo.info/netrenderer/index.php

Comment: yes in IE Tester it shows fine. But I am using adobe browserlab. https://browserlab.adobe.com/en-us/index.html?sc=bl&rc=1&lang=en_US#state=use;zoom=100;url=http%3A%2F%2Findivar.info%2Fgodsak%2Fnode%2F18;view=0;browsers=WXPIE6000%2CWXPIE7000

Comment: it will be a bug in browserlab - IE NetRenderer actually performs a screen shot on an IE machine. If in doubt check browsershorts.org, or install a virtual machine with XP that will install IE6. It will work fine though, browserlabs can be buggy.