# Body background image not showing in IE

Tags: css, google-chrome, internet-explorer, linked-list

Everything else displays correctly except the body background in IE but it is OK on chrome. Whereas it just disappears in IE. But it does show the background color and not the image

2) the "main" tag in my CSS is set with
    Z-index: -1;
Hence all the links in my page are not functioning. Is there anyway I could go around this??

My site URL is at http://my-name.orgfree.com

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6842126/css-body-background-image-not-showing-in-ie-6?rq=1

maybe it will be helpfull

Comment: Thanks. It shows fine on netrenderer. Must be a bug from my browser then. How do I remove those blue boxes outside every image link since text-decoration doesn't work on them??

Answer (score 0):

1.
your linkes doesn't work - syntax is wrong

```
             <li><a href=#> <div>SERMONS</div></a></li>
            <li><a href=#> <div>CONTACT US</div></a></li>
            <li><a href=#> <div>GALLERY</div></a></li>
            <li><a href=#> <div>ABOUT US</div></a></li>
```

should be

```
    <li><a href="#"> <div>SERMONS</div></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"> <div>CONTACT US</div></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"> <div>GALLERY</div></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"> <div>ABOUT US</div></a></li>
```

they will start to work when u will have links under, for example

```
    <li><a href="sermons.html"> <div>SERMONS</div></a></li>
    <li><a href="contact_us.html"> <div>CONTACT US</div></a></li>
    <li><a href="gallery.html"> <div>GALLERY</div></a></li>
    <li><a href="about_us.html"> <div>ABOUT US</div></a></li>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_link_href.asp

Comment: 1.validate your code here

http://validator.w3.org/
2. use great editors like brackets, phpstorm,

Comment: you do not understand. i intend the links to redirect to my index.html thats why they have this -----> "#". the links lead to the index.html in internet explorer but do not work in chrome. also the links in the coupon div

Comment: Hello may. I found out the cause of the problem I have with chrome and edited my question. Please scroll up and reread. Thanks

Comment: Yea. Any idea on how I can go around the z-index ish?? I want the main tag to appear under the header with that shadow effect

Comment: z-index works only with positioning

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

Comment: I was using relative positioning instead of absolute. All the same i can't thank you enough!!! God bless

Answer (score 0):

1. start reading about html, css syntaxes and how to write names
2. it's bad to write  --> can write the_end.css , the-end.css, theEnd.css ...
3. you have a lot of syntax error and it's defficult to know why your site doesn't work in IE
4. start to learn Bootstrap or Foundation and build responsive websites

good luck ;)

Comment: i have corrected your "the end" issue though that was much ado over nothing. i've checked my code on the css and html validators; html has only one error while the css has absolutely no errors. i really do not know what page you found 'a lot of syntax error'. statements like this can put someone down after so much hardwork on my part.

Comment: if my codes are looking tattered, you can use the "html tidy" function of your code editor to make it legible. my dreamweaver has expired so i'm left with good old notepad. bear with me

Answer (score 0):

```
body {
    background-image: url("bg_image.jpg");
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

i set background-image and it works in chrome, firefox, IE
is your image in the same folder as html,css files or you have folder -img- where u keep your images ??

Comment: Yes it is in the same folder

Comment: 1. try with another  image
2. maybe it's from your browser IE

Comment: I just did. No difference. I even changed browser mode but it didn't change anything. As for my other question, other links outside my main tag are working but every other link in the main tag is inactive